# how to parse this sample of json

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode

I assumed this as an array and I typed

```
_price1=[venues valueForKey:@"price_total”];
```

I got this an an output ,I expected to get 6 as the count when i typed 
this

```
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)_price1.count);
```

The fact is that I got 1 as the output for the count.

```
(
    (
    772,
    912,
    912,
    912,
    912,
    935
  )
)
```

My doubt is how can I parse it so that the ouput is an array.Do tell me the meaning about ( ) [this brackets] when json is considered.

my code is

Ok my code is :

```
-(void)initialize{

id venues = [[_json valueForKey:@"hotels_prices"]valueForKey:@"agent_prices”];

_price1=[venues valueForKey:@"price_total"];//global array...
NSLog(@"%@", _price1);
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)_price1.count);}
```

json is: this is (id venues ) according to the code

```
   (

      (

         {

        id = 146;
        "price_per_room_night" = 158;
        "price_total" = 944;
        "room_offers" =             (        //problem
                            {
                available = 0;
                "meal_plan" = "Room only";
                "policy_dto" =                     {
                };
                rooms =                     (
                                            {
                        adults = 0;
                        children = 0;
                        type = "Double room";
                        "type_id" = "ROOMTYPE_DOUBLE";
                    }
                );//problem
            },
```

//see that brackets (); is the problem

Comment: We really need to see the input to say something meaningful about why your code doesn't work. Showing your code also wouldn't hurt!

Comment: Yeah man, welcome on stackoverflow :) Make sure to always re-read  your question and put yourself in a postiion where you are completely out of context (our position). If you wouldn't have enough information, that means you need to edit your question. Right now, you do need to show us the json you're talking about and exactly how you're working with it.

Comment: Ok my code is                                                                                              -(void)initialize{
id venues = [[_json valueForKey:@"hotels_prices"]valueForKey:@"agent_prices"];
    _price1=[venues valueForKey:@"price_total"];//global array...
    NSLog(@"%@", _price1);
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)_price1.count);
}

Comment: update your question with the code. It's hard to read code in comments

Comment: "see that brackets ()" That means an array.

Comment: in this line `id venues = [[_json valueForKey:@"hotels_prices"]valueForKey:@"agent_prices”];` the second comma are a different type of character, try changing it

Comment: Use `valueForKey` only if KVC is *really* intended.

Comment: Can you tell me the full form of KVC ?

Comment: So how I am supposed to parse this json into an array

Comment: **K**ey-**V**alue **C**oding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep! I got the answer as Matt told the brackets (); should be treated as an array

the

```
    id venues = [[_json valueForKey:@"hotels_prices"]valueForKey:@"agent_prices”];
```

gives the above json but if I want to get the meal plan

```
    NSArray*meal=[[_json valueForKey:@"room_offers"]valueForKey:@"meal_plan”];
```

Then I can type:

```
  NSArray*meal_plan=[meal objectAtIndex:0];//or any other index not beyond the array limit..
```

We can get the desired output and
the array meal can be parsed normally.